# Condition in a dynamic CASE WHEN in a cursor in SQL Server 2018

Tags: sql, sql-server

When trying to specify a condition in a `CASE WHEN` sequence as the example shown below where one part of the condition is built dynamically SQL Server seems not to perform the comparison.

```
SET @QRY_SELECT = @QRY_SELECT + '

,CASE
WHEN ' + SELECT DogTypeId FROM Dogs WHERE DogColorId = @Color + ' = 3 THEN
   1
END AS [...]
'
```

Any ideas to fix this? Is this code correct?

Seems not to be problem of the datatype of `DogTypeId` (int).

Expected to get "1" if the `CASE WHEN` sequence were correct.

Comment: Your code is possibly a [documented antipattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) that should never be used. Additionally, which version of SQL Server are you using vecause you are *not* usering version 2018.

Comment: You can debug dynamic SQL using the print statement.

Comment: @Stu I don't see how it is. The antipattern is about using the assignment in a query. Surely it's fine with a `set`?

Comment: There's no SQL Server 2018 and SQL Server 2008 is [reached the end of even Extended Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/general/end-support-sql-server-2008) in 2019. There's *no* need for dynamic SQL in this case anyway, you can include the query itself in the `WHEN` clause actually simplify it

Comment: @GSerg there are *multiple* antipatterns in this query. `WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Dogs WHERE DogColorId = @Color  and DogTypeID=3) THEN` removes the need for dynamic SQL entirely. Along with the potential SQL injection risks (are we sure DogTypeID isn't a varchar(max) for "flexibility"?) and multiple results. A CTE would probably help clean up the query too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It may be, but it's not *that* antipattern.

Comment: thank you for your reply, and yes it is sql server 18 (not 2018). I'll try to apply what you suggest.

Comment: I read the initial line as a select and just saw the string concatenation so probably the link I posted is not relevant @GSerg; besides the OP has only included a fragment not the entire query so it's unknown whether they actually need d-sql or not.

Comment: @francollado99 Unless you're talking to us from 2027 it's unlikely you are using SQL Server 18 either, the current version is 16.

Comment: @francollado99 there's no SQL Server 18 either. You're probably confusing the SSMS version with the actual SQL Server version. SSMS is a DBA tool, not the database

Comment: @francollado99 what does the full query look like ? It's highly likely that the entire query can be simplified and run a lot faster than trying to execute individual parts separately. N "small" queries are N times slower than 1 complete well-written query on indexed tables. Especially if those "small" queries end up scanning an entire table each time

Comment: Run `SELECT @@VERSION` against your SQL Server database to find out its **real** version number - 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 or 2022 ....

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for dynamic SQL at all in this case. The Dog check can be done in advance and stored in a variable, or it can be included in the `CASE` clause directly, eg :

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                FROM Dogs 
                WHERE DogColorId = @Color  and DogTypeID=3) 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE NULL
END AS DogsExist,
```

or

```
declare @dogs_exist bit=NULL

select @dogs_exist=1 
FROM Dogs 
WHERE DogColorId = @Color  and DogTypeID=3;
```

And then use the variable

```
SELECT ......,@dogs_exist as DogsExist,....
```

It's highly likely that the entire query can be simplified and optimized so there's no need to calculate `dogs_exist` separately